# regex: remove double quotes from Json values

Tags: regex

I am absolutly awful at regex and I now have a problem I can only fix by regex

I have a json string that has double quotes in the wrong places

for example:

```
[
  {
    "customerid": "1234",
    "price": "123.456",
    "foo","bar"
  }
]
```

I would like to remove the double quotes from all the fields that are numbers (customerid, price) and keep them for any alpha numeric characters(foo)

Is there a magic regex that can help me achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove double quotes around "simple" numbers use the following regex pattern:

```
"(-?\d+(\.\d+)?)"
```

substitution group is `$1`

https://regex101.com/r/gfVkaa/1

Comment: Thanks for this @Roman, what do you mean by "Simple" numbers? what arent Simple

Comment: here is an example of some complex numbers: `1.3e-5`, `300-400i`

Comment: ah thanks, i think ill stick with simple numbers for now :)

Answer (score 0):

with `sed`

```
$ sed -r 's/"([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*)"/\1/' file
```

you can fine tune to work on values only as well, but not sure needed in json format.

Comment: Any chance you can give me an example on regex101? Ive never used sed